# Play Framework DB upgrades with Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, playframework

I'm using the Play Framework (1.2.4) I created a `UserAccount` object, deployed it to Heroku. Worked great. Then I added an `isAdmin` field to the `UserAccount` class, deployed it locally and it worked fine (but I'm using the in-memory DB), then I deployed it on Heroku and now I'm getting the following exception:

```
2011-12-23T09:03:35+00:00 app[web.1]: play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not load an entity: [models.UserAccount#2]
2011-12-23T09:03:35+00:00 app[web.1]: PersistenceException occured : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not load an entity: [models.UserAccount#2]
...
2011-12-23T09:03:35+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not load an entity: [models.UserAccount#2]
2011-12-23T09:03:35+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not load an entity: [models.UserAccount#2]
2011-12-23T09:03:35+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column useraccoun0_.isadmin does not exist
...
```

I've searched around to figure out how to do DB upgrades and the Play website says that Hibernate should be handling that for me.

Here are my DB properties:

```
%prod.db=${DATABASE_URL}
%prod.jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
%prod.jpa.ddl=update
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run the Play database evolutions on Heroku:

```
heroku run "play evolutions:apply --%prod"
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll give this a try. Is this a one time thing or do I do it everytime there are DB changes? Also, is this something safe to do with live data or would I want something more manual with I have a large dataset?

Comment: Oh I see. This is the manual update scripts. I'll play with these then. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This solution is just for Play 1.  For Play 2 can you ask another question for this?

Answer (score 7):

The property *jpa.ddl* should be *none* when in Prod mode. Update is risky in production as it may break the DB (as it seems it's happening to you!

The proper way to manage this would be:

1. Install Heroku SQL console on your Heroku app (from [here](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-sql-console))
2. Change *jpa.ddl* to *none*
3. Connect to your heroku database using the SQL console and apply any fixes/updates you have to
4. Reupload the app to Heroku (remember to do a new commit locally or Heroku will say the code is already up to date)

This should work.

Comment: The Heroku SQL console is Ruby so it can't be installed on a Play app.

Comment: @JamesWard That's not true, I have it in my box running and works perfectly. It opens a PSQL terminal and I can toy around with the db (using shared DB).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  How do you "Install Heroku SQL console on your Heroku app" when the app is a Play app?

Comment: @JamesWard see the link I put in the answer (this one: https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-sql-console). I followed those steps and it works. Maybe my way of explaining it was wrong (not English native, sometimes I mix sentences a bit, sorry!) but I can tell you that it works :)

Comment: Oh!  I get it now.  Sorry.  It's a Heroku CLI plugin.  That will work with any app.  Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @PereVillega Dude, this was perfect!  Thanks so much for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note, the instruction for heroku have you include db in your .gitignore, so if you use this:

heroku run "play evolutions:apply --%prod"

You will get an error/warning. However, to my surprise (and delight) restarting the process did indeed apply my evolutions and updated my db (verified with heroku SQL console mentioned below :-)). A bit mysterious how this worked, but happy it did!