# Playframework: How to execute an evolutions script

Tags: mysql, heroku, playframework

I am using play framework 1.25 and have deployed a web app to the heroku platform.
When I tried to log into the app, there was an exception because the database (MySQL) was not upto date. So I have created an evolutions script which adds the field which was missing from a table.

I have now deployed my latest code to heroku which includes the new script (10.sql) but am still getting an exception.
Could someone tell me how I go about executing the script? I thought it got run automatically but i'm new to play.

Here is a snippet from the logs:

WARN  ~
WARN  ~ Your database is not up to date.
WARN  ~ Use `play evolutions` command to manage database evolutions.
ERROR ~

heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

Answer (score 0):

You should use the heroku run command to execute the "play evolutions:apply" command with whatever arguments suit your environment.  Example below:

```
heroku run "play evolutions:apply --%prod"
```

This has been asked before: [Play Framework DB upgrades with Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614127/play-framework-db-upgrades-with-heroku)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see that one. 
I'm trying to run the command on the staging database, would it be the same or would I just change to --%staging ?